# ajax call fails to load php script that updates column information

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax call to a php script that goes into a database and updates a row  of information. If I type the link into the browser with the supplied information I want to change then it works fine without an issue. I have SEVERAL ajax calls set up the same way as this one and they all work without a problem. Can't figure out why this ajax call to the php script is failing to do anything.

javascript call:

```
function updateInfo(userID, email, username, password){
    var validGT;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200){
                validGT = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    if(validGT == "Success!"){
                        var error = document.getElementById("update-error-message");
                        error.innerHTML = "Updated!";
                    }else{
                        var error = document.getElementById("update-error-message");
                        error.style.color = "Red";
                        error.innerHTML = "error occured";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "updateInfo.php?userID=" + userID + "&email=" + email + "&gamertag=" + gamertag + "&password=" + password, true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

php script:

```
****connect to database and such****
$userID = $_GET{"userID"};
$email = $_GET{"email"};
$username = $_GET{"username"};
$password = $_GET{"password"};

if($password != "null"){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$email', username='$username', password='$password' WHERE uid='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Success!";
}else{
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$email' AND username='$username' WHERE uid='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "Success!";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

I get a response back from the ajax call saying "Success!" however it doesn't actually do anything to the information in the database. I used firebug to make sure the information was being passed correctly and it is. So I am at loss here. What is up? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: should ($password != "null") be (!empty($password))?

Comment: syntax error on the second SQL statement?

Comment: +1 @IliaG Should have "," not "AND"

Comment: Also should look into using mysql_real_escape_string to prevent security issues.

Comment: @ChrisK I have a check in my javascript in earlier functions that if a password is not being changed then it actually sends the string "null". Doesn't actually check if the password is in fact null. A little misleading on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks weird try

```
$userID = $_GET["userID"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$username = $_GET["username"];
$password = $_GET["password"];
```

If that does not help, try to debug/echo the query to see whats happening

also change

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$email' AND username='$username' WHERE uid='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET email='$email', username='$username' WHERE uid='$userID'") or die(mysql_error());
```

but since you've never gotten any sql error, password seems to be "null" all the time

Comment: I figured out the error but you made me realize another. Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The SQL UPDATE syntax in the else statement is incorrect, you are using AND instead of a comma

```
"UPDATE users SET email='$email', username='$username' WHERE uid='$userID'"
```

On a side note you are also accepting data from the request via $_GET and you are not sanitizing that data before running it against the database.

Comment: I did miss this somehow. Fixed the first line must not have done the second. Thanks for that.